# SOLR configuration for Multiple Environments

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I am new to SOLR but I have setup the SOLR Cloud and have setup a core "participant_dev". We have multiple environments namely., CI,Dev,QA,UAT and Prod.

For the single core, the configuration is simple enough. In the **Spring Boot** application yaml add the solr server url like so

```
spring:
  data:
    solr:
      host: server url
```

The solr Document is annotated with

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "participant_dev")
public class Solr Participant{

     ....
}
```

This works but now the requirement is as the application moves to different environments I have to setup solr cores like 'participant_ci','participant_qa','participant_uat' and such. Can you advise as to how to change the solr core name based on the environment. So that,
    In CI,

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "participant_ci")
public class Solr Participant{

     ....
}

In QA,

@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "participant_qa")
public class Solr Participant{

     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set by creating solr client bean in Application class and removing @SolrDocument annotation. So the default collection would be as specified.

```
@Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient()
    {
        CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.data.solr.zk-host"));
        client.setDefaultCollection("participant_"+env.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
        return client;
    }
```

The other option would be by creating custom repository, but that would add lot of unwanted code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how would this work if I had multiple collections being used by the Application??

Comment: is there a way of doing


          @SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "${solrcore}")


and read solrcore from property file?

Comment: I tried the same but didnt find anything.. Couldnt find a way to define collection name at runtime.

Comment: Just found this ticket in the spring solr jira. 


https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-304?jql=project%20%3D%20DATASOLR%20AND%20text%20~%20%22solrdocument%22